# UITableView is getting stuck when loading data from UICollectionviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

- I have a Uitableview in which i am loading custom uitableviewcells
  and all that cells are calling a class which draw a collectionview
  with scroll in it depending on amount of data,
- so I'have seen that when I scroll then my UITableview take a jam on
  those cells which are adopting scrollview then after a very narrow
  second everything is fine but when I scroll again then it again
  happen
- I know that the problem is I am drawing cells on each time but I have
  also take a look by initiating an array of views and then pass the
  specific view to the cell on run time but strangely it got more stuck
  when I am doing this.

  Kindly help me on this

Answer (score 0):

My Approach in your scenario would be to create “Section Header” and “Section Footer” for UICollectionView like the approach in this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/ which i feel much simpler and easy to implement.